# For Next loop to move excess texts to a new added row

Tags: vba

I'm trying to move texts after 40 characters to the next row added in Excel but the code below skips the for loop. When F8 key is used it jumps from 'For i = 1 to i = 50' to 'End Sub'.

```
Sub TextLimit()

Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To i = 50


 If Len(Cells(i, 1)) > 40 Then

 Rows(i + 1).Insert

 Cells(i + 1, 1) = Mid(Cells(i, 1), 41, Len(Cells(i, 1)) - 40)

 Else


End If


Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: `For i = 1 To i = 50` means `For i = 1 To False` and `False = 0` - You want `For i = 1 To 50`

Answer (score 0):

I added the ending loop variable `iend` and variable incrementation when conidition is fulfilled

```
Sub TextLimit()

Dim i As Long, iend as long
iend = 50
For i = 1 To iend 


 If Len(Cells(i, 1)) > 40 Then

 Rows(i + 1).Insert

 Cells(i + 1, 1) = Mid(Cells(i, 1), 41, Len(Cells(i, 1)) - 40)
 iend =iend +1
 Else


 End If


Next i


End Sub
```